# how to get volume at bottom of chart in Tradingview

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I'm embarrassed to ask a newbie question like this, but I am unable to get the volume histogram in Tradingview chart. Is there a simple switch that I can't find? I want it at the bottom of the chart, underneath each candle.
Much appreciated

Comment: You mean, you want your indicator to be located at the bottom of the chart as the volume indicator? Or are you literally asking how to add the volume indicator to your chart?

Comment: Yes, I can’t figure out how to make the volume indicator visible at the bottom of the chart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search and the built-in indicator `volume` from the indicators list.

[image]